# Align Horizontal Rule in Css, Not aligning properly

Tags: css, reactjs

How can I do something like this?

[image: ovaredn.png]

The Orange Line should be on the same Line as the Instruction Text, I have this as my CSS Code

```css
.InstructionText{
    margin-bottom: auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 29px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #007FC0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.hr-rule{
    position: absolute;
    border: 7px solid #FF9900;
    width: 400px;
}
```

But rather than have the above image, I have this Instead.

[image: 3333.png]

And using it inside the code I have this

```
import React from 'react';
import './app-styles.css';
import Vector from './Vector.png'
import ie_logo from './ie_logo.png';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <header className="header">
        <img src={Vector} style={{margin:7, flexDirection:'column', alignItems: 'center'}} alt="Vector" />
        <img src={ie_logo} style={{margin:7, flexDirection: 'row', width:114, height:25}} alt="ie_logo" />
        <p className="needhelpText">REGISTERED? LOGIN</p>
        </header>
            <form>
                <div className="InstructionText">
                    payment
                </div>
                <div className="hr-rule">
                </div>
            </form>
        <footer className="footer">
        <a href="#" className="footerLinks"> Privacy Policy | &nbsp; </a>
        <a href="#" className="footerLinks">Do Not Sell My Personal Information | &nbsp; </a>
        <a href="#" className="footerLinks">Advertising Guidelines | &nbsp;</a>   
        <a href="#" className="footerLinks">Site Map  &nbsp;</a>  

        <div className="copyrightText">
        © Copyright 2021 | Lucas Tech | All Rights Reserved
        </div>
        <div className="footerLogo"> 
        <img src={ie_logo}  alt="ie_logo" />
        </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a very complicated method. Why not use a pseudo-element?

```css
.InstructionText {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 29px;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #007FC0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
}

.InstructionText:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 7px solid #FF9900;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  width: 200px; /* or whatever width you require */
}
```

```html
<div class="InstructionText">
  payment
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason being that div is a block element by default, thus it will stack on top of each others. We can achieve your goal by using flex, which put the 2 divs side-by-side:

**HTML:**

```
<form>
  <div class="header-container">

    <div class="InstructionText">
      payment
    </div>
    <div class="hr-rule"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.InstructionText{

    margin-bottom: auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 29px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #007FC0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.hr-rule{
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: #FF9900;
    width: 400px;
}
```

For the thick line, instead of using border, it's more efficient and understandable to just make a div with the width and 14px height, which achieve the same thing.